# Why do forms require an Entity in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to understand how to create a basic form in symfony2. I am aware of all the perks for using DQL / Entities to manipulate database records.

However, I am not sure I understand why I would want to create an Entity for search functionality? Right now, my search functionality works well, but I don't understand what the justification is to using entities for a simple one input form? It seems like overkill

Thanks for the clarification

My search controller looks something like this:

```
 //namespace etc..

class Search
{
    protected $word;
    protected $page;

    public function getQ(){
        return $this->word;
    }
    public function setQ($word){
        return $this->word = $word;
    }
    public function getPage(){
        return $this->page;
    }
    public function setPage($page){
        return $this->page;
    }
}
```

Comment: arrays work just fine in forms.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create Entity for simple forms like contact form, search form, etc. Forms are often being used to create or update data in the database, but they do not require them.

Here is an example of usage of the symfony2 form, which does everything without entity (including validation):

**[How to create a contact form using Symfony2](http://www.lucas.courot.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-symfony2.html)**